# Will dynamic reduce function result in re-constructing B-Tree

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am a little confused about how CouchDB operates. So far I have learned that requesting a map function of a view for the first time will cause couchdb to construct a b-tree index that gets referenced in the following runs.

What I am unsure about is, does the b-tree gets re-constructed if my reduce function returns different document every time the view is requested?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reduce() function doesn't return documents, it returns the reduced value for the given set of values. The schema of map-reduce goes as follows. The map() function is called for each of the documents in the database. From map() you can emit() any number of the view rows. You do it with a code like:

```
emit(key, value);
```

Its important to note that map() is called only once for each document revision, later on this result is cached. The result can only depend on the document, you cannot pass any parameters from the request or emit random numbers.

Than, when you query your view, and you have the reduce() function defined, it will be called for all the rows emitted for the documents matching the query key range. Again, there is no way to pass arguments from the request. The result can only depend on the values passed to reduce() function.

Internally the b-tree structure is used to cache and minimize the amount of computation needed. You can have multiple views defined with the same map() function code and different reduce() functions. CouchDB is smart enough to shard the output of map() and not call it more times than needed.

I hope this clears out a little. Good luck!

-- edit below to answer comment about selecting random row in reduce() --

In general using random in map() or reduce() is against the design of map-reduce procedure. If you use randomness inside map() or reduce() function, the random result will get cached. The result of reduce() is cached for different subsets of the rows. You don't know or control how many times the reduce() function is called to calculated the final result of the query. If you perform the exact same query twice, the second time might not even need 1 call.

Also the design on reduce() function requires that the following relation is satisfied:

```
reduce(reduce(a) + reduce(b)) = reduce(a + b)
```

*a* and *b* above are the key-value ranges. This obviously doesn't stand if you use random inside the reduce body.

As far as I understand you just want to get the random row from the view. Why don't you just use a reduce="_count" in your view. Than you can perform your task in two queries:

- first query to get the count of rows
- second query with *reduce=false&skip=random(count)&limit=1* to get the random row of the view. Here the *random(count)* is calculated on the client side.

Comment: thank you for clarification Marek. Please correct me if I am wrong here. So, I have a view defined to return me a number of rows and a reduce function that 'reduces' it to a single **randomly** picked row. As I understand, this arrangement will not hit the performance, am I correct?

Comment: I had a look at 'skip' and had concerns about it because skip would still access each row but will not return data from it resulting in degrading performance when you need to skip thousands of rows (and the application that we are developing is expected to have many thousands of users)

Comment: Using skip is just another way of specifying the query range. Of course the view index needs to be calculated, but its the case for any type of query you do, and the result is cached by the server.

Comment: last question, bare with me please... Would that mean that if the requests to views with random result reduce functions would use too much cache and slow it down to a crawl eventually? or does couchdb do some housecleaning is it goes?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a problem with efficiency. I just think it wouldn't work as you expect because of caching. To make it clear: lets say you always query the view with the reduce=true with open key range (all the documents) and have the reduce() function which picks one of the rows at random. What I think will happen is that the reduce() will only be called once, the first time you query the view. Later on, because of caching, you would be given the same result. That's not random :)

Comment: Ok I see, thank you I will look out for this "effect". So far I have tested random reduce solution with curl and it was returning me different result every time as expected.

Comment: Re-tested my random reduced view in our dev environment(node.js + nano), it does return a cached result. (was trying it out via curl and couchdb was not caching it that way)

Comment: I think you need to include one more variable in the test: the number of view rows. I think there is a limit, below which couchdb internally doesn't yet create any intermediary nodes of the btree. In simple words: if you only have few documents, the reduced result is calculated with a single call of reduce() function. If you have more documents it splits the range, than calls reduce for the each part and than rereduce for intermediary results.

Comment: it does look like it, but since it is clear that this approach would not work with the large amount of docs we are adopting a different approach which is more in line with the couchDB way :) anyways, thank you for your support this discussion definitely improved my understanding of nosql db